# Python SublimeText plugin - No module named Yaml

Tags: python, yaml, sublimetext

I'm using OS X with Sublime text build 2181, and I am having trouble using the Yaml module in a Sublime Text plugin.

I have installed PyYaml by doing `python setup.py install`. When I go to the python console, and try `import yaml` I have no problems. But when I try to save my Sublime Text plugin with the `import yaml` statement, I keep getting `ImportError: No module name yaml`

I'm using the pre-installed version of Python, version 2.7.

Last line of the install output:

`Writing /Users/me/Developer/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7.egg-info`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Users/me/Developer/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7` doesn't seem like a pre-installed version of Python on a Mac. Can you try to identify the system-wide Python installation and use the explicit path to the python executable to execute `setup.py install`? Then try the Sublime Text plug-in.

The default Mac OS X Python should be located at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/...`

Comment: Ya you're right. It must have gotten installed when I added Macports or Brew or something. When I do a `which python` I get: `/Users/me/Developer/bin/python`

Comment: You can either get Sublime Text to use the right version of python (somehow, e.g. by manipulating the PATH when starting it), or install PyYaml as in my original answer, by using the full path to the system-wide executable.